# How to set items checked in my listview if Listview.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL is set (programaticly)

Tags: android, listview, selection, screen-rotation

i have a problem to restore checked items after screen rotation.
I use Listview with custom adapter and Listview.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL to select items.
Now if i rotate my screen CAB is still present but my selection is not.
Is it possible restore checked state of my list view ?
I have saved all positions of checked items in onSavedInstanceState and restore them after rotation, but if i use listview.setItemChecked(position, true); for all of them they dont get checked...(All positions are getting restored properly).

Thx

Comment: Are you using one of the android layouts for the items or your own?  Did you call notifyDatasetChanged() after reseting the checked items?

Comment: for list items ? i use my own layout. i load data for my list in AsyncTask and setadapter in there.

Comment: So, what do you do in the adapter's getView() method when it is checked?

Comment: nothing i use only ListView.MultiChoiceModeListener in my ListFragment   and use callback methods. My Listitem is just a RelativeLayout with 3 Textviews and get highlighted

Comment: mListView = getListView();
        if (mListView != null){
            mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
            mListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(this);

Comment: "Is it possible restore checked state of my list view ?" -- that should happen automatically.

Comment: Show us how you create the ArrayAdapter (I want to see what you put in the constructor).  Based on that I think I can answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem. 
I was overwriting ArrayList of recoverd items after it got recovered.... but thx for help.